# Revert style when click on other Geojson point

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I have created a Google Map with multiple Geojson data layers, placing custom icons and make that same icon change when clicked, so far so good.

What I'm trying to do is to revert the icon back to its original state when clicking on another Geojson point of the same data layer (and/or other layers).

It sounds simple (and probably is), but I cant seem to figure it out.

```js
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var offices = new google.maps.Data();

offices.addGeoJson({
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [4.403528, 51.260561]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Location": "Antwerp",
        "Country": "BE"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [9.986818, 53.554377]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Location": "Hamburg",
        "Country": "DE"
      }
    }
  ]
});

offices.setStyle({
  icon: 'images/icons/logo-1.png'
});
offices.setMap(map);
offices.addListener('click', function(event) {

  var office_location = event.feature.getProperty("Location");
  var office_country = event.feature.getProperty("Country");

  infowindow.setContent(office_location + " - " + office_country);

  infowindow.setPosition(event.feature.getGeometry().get());
  infowindow.setOptions({
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -30)
  });

  offices.overrideStyle(event.feature, {
    icon: 'images/icons/logo-2.png'
  });
  infowindow.open(map);
  map.panTo(event.latLng);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
  offices.revertStyle();
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.close();
  offices.revertStyle();
});
```

I hope you could help me out with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the previous feature; revert it when you click on a new feature:

```
if (previousFeature != null) 
  offices.revertStyle(previousFeature);

offices.overrideStyle(event.feature, {
  icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png'
});
previousFeature = event.feature;
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/vvxbzkq9/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.260561, 4.403528),
      zoom: 5,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var offices = new google.maps.Data();

  offices.addGeoJson({
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [4.403528, 51.260561]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Location": "Antwerp",
        "Country": "BE"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [9.986818, 53.554377]
      },
      "properties": {
        "Location": "Hamburg",
        "Country": "DE"
      }
    }]
  });

  offices.setStyle({
    icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png'
  });
  offices.setMap(map);
  var previousFeature = null;
  offices.addListener('click', function(event) {

    var office_location = event.feature.getProperty("Location");
    var office_country = event.feature.getProperty("Country");

    infowindow.setContent(office_location + " - " + office_country);

    infowindow.setPosition(event.feature.getGeometry().get());
    infowindow.setOptions({
      pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(0, -30)
    });
    if (previousFeature != null) offices.revertStyle(previousFeature);
    offices.overrideStyle(event.feature, {
      icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png'
    });
    previousFeature = event.feature;
    infowindow.open(map);
    map.panTo(event.latLng);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
    offices.revertStyle();
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    offices.revertStyle();
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Hi geocodezip, thanks for your quick and very helpfull input. Your solution works exactly as it should.